# Does $S^1 \times S^3$ admit a complex structure?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

Does $S^1 \times S^3$ admit a complex structure?

It is parallelizable, so it admits an almost complex structure...is there a nice way to see that this is or is not integrable?

Comment: Look up *Hopf surfaces*. These are complex surfaces diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$, but they cannot be Kähler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which almost complex structure do you have in mind? In fact they are better than paralelizable ($S^1$ and $S^2$), their tangen bundles are Lie algebras so checking [Nijenhuis tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Integrable_almost_complex_structures) is very easy (it is linear problem) whatever structure given by that paralelization by fundamental vector fields you have in mind. It is even better, since both $S^1$ and $S^3$ are compact Lie groups you can find a left invariant complex structure on $S^1 \times S^3$ so **Yes** it admit complex structure.

**EDIT:**
The structure you are indicating is not vell defined since you have to choose an identification of tangent space with $\mathbb{R}^4$. You would like to write something like that:

$\bullet$ $TS^1$ is paralelizable by a single vector field $\xi$ let say

$\bullet$ $TS^3$ is paralelizable by vector fields $e_1, e_2, e_3$

that vector fields $lifts$ to vector fields on $S^1 \times S^3$ and give a paralelization of $T(S^1 \times S^3)$ where Lie bracket between them is:

$\bullet$ $[\xi, e_i]=0, [e_1,e_2]=e_3, [e_2,e_3]=e_1, [e_3,e_1]=e_2.$

Now you can define an almost complex structure for example by:

$$e_2 \mapsto \xi \mapsto - e_2$$
$$e_1 \mapsto e_3 \mapsto -e_1.$$
That is an almost complex structure yet you have to chcecke if it is integrable - so if $$[J,J](X,Y)=0$$ for all $X,Y \in \{e_1,e_2, e_3, \xi\}$.

Comment: I was thinking of the almost complex structure defined by taking the standard one at each point $p \in S^1 \times S^3$: $$J_p: T_p(S^1 \times S^3)=\mathbb R^{4} \rightarrow T_p (S^1 \times S^3)=\mathbb R^{4},$$
given by
$$J_p = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & I \\
    -I & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: If you don't mind explaining, how did you compute those Lie brackets in your third bullet? And excuse me if it is standard, but what is the notation $[J,J](X,Y)$?

Comment: Firstely you have to remember we have lifted original $e_i$'s to the product and similarly $\xi$ so for example when you write these fields in local product chart $\phi \times \psi$ they will be given by functions depending only on $\phi$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ ($\psi$ respectively). Now you can compute the bracket in that local chart.